# Unable to print vector values from map in maps

Tags: c++, dictionary

I am trying to print out the whole contents of map of maps but keep encountering into issues.
Here is my map initialisation `map<int, map<int, vector<int>>> myMap;`

I have tried the following code:

```
for( auto const & cit : myMap)
    {
        cout << cit.first << " : ";
        auto const & imap = cit.second;
        for( auto const & cit2 : imap )
        {
            cout << cit2.first << ":" << cit2.second << ","; // errors out
            //cout << cit2.first << ":"; // works, but it is not printing out the vector<int> portion
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
```

As mentioned above, as soon as `cit2.second` is used, I got the following error:
`error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::basic_ostream<char>' and 'const std::vector<int>')|`

can someone kindly give me some insights?

Comment: You would need to loop again over `cit2.second` to `cout` your vector elements

Comment: What's unclear about the error `'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::basic_ostream<char>' and 'const std::vector<int>')`? There is no `operator<<` defined for a stream, and `std::vector<int>`. You either need to define it yourself, or print the contents of `std::vector<int>`, by looping over it.

Comment: Is it correct to assume that you don't understand the error message?  Is that what you're asking for insights about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it like this.

```
for( auto const & cit : myMap)
    {
        cout << cit.first << " : ";
        auto const & imap = cit.second;
        for( auto const & cit2 : imap )
        {
            cout << cit2.first << ":";
            auto const &vec = cit2.second;
            for(auto const &i : vec)
            {
                cout<<i<<" ";
            }cout<<endl;   
            //cout << cit2.first << ":"; // works, but it is not printing out the vector<int> portion
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
```